# Launch my virtual Android device via command line

Tags: android, command-line, android-virtual-device

I have Android Studio and I have created virtual device that I want to launch via Android Studio.

In my `avd` folder I have this `Pixel_XL_API_27.adv` file that created.

Now I want to launch my virtual Android device via command line. First I wrote `emulator -list-avds` and received `Pixel_XL_API_27`.

But when I type `emulator Pixel_XL_API_27` and the result that I received is this message:

```
No AVD specified. use @foo or -avd foo to lunch a virtual device named foo
```

**Update**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this:

```
emulator -avd Pixel_XL_API_27
```

For more information about options see https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline

**UPDATE**

Be sure to set `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable and type proper command in your terminal/cmd:

Window:

```
%ANDROID_HOME%\emulator\emulator.exe -avd Pixel_XL_API_27
```

Linux:

```
$ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator -avd Pixel_XL_API_27
```

The problem is sometimes (mostly in Windows) when you add `emulator` folder in `PATH` variable, and use `emulator -avd avd_name` command, current working directory in used to search for other SDK tools, instead of real `ANDROID_HOME` directory. So you should provide full path for `emulator.exe` file to start your emulator.

Comment: Now i got cannot find AVD system path, please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

Comment: What i need to add the environment path ? (i think i have almost all)

Comment: If you install Android SDK via Android Studio or download from developer.android.com website, you don't need the `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` variable. set the `ANDROID_HOME` variable to the sdk path and try this command: `$ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator -avd Pixel_XL_API_27`. The problem is you should specify the full path of `emulator` file instead of adding the emulator directory to the `$PATH`

Comment: ANDROID_HOME is not recognized... although i set it inside environment variables despite the face that this ANDROID_HOME target is the sdk folder

Comment: Are you sure you set `ANDROID_HOME` correctly? `export ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/android/sdk` and then `source .bashrc` (or whatever your file name is). don't forget to use `source` after declaring ANDROID_HOME

Comment: When i try your update i received The system cannot find the path specified and when i try only '$ANDROID_HOME$' i received '$ANDROID_HOME$' is not recognized as an internal or external command, i add the picture that show that i have this var, maybe i need to add another thing ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190758/discussion-between-sepehr-behroozi-and-falukky).